# How to pass a variable from one ActionResult to another ActionResult? (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to use the value of a string variable passed to one ActionResult, within another ActionResult.. How could i go about doing this?

```
public ActionResult PassCategoryPlaceHolder(string placeHolder)
        {

            var result = placeHolder;
            return RedirectToAction("EditCategory", result);
        }
```

I want to be able to use 'result' in my other ActionResult as follows:

```
public ActionResult EditCategory()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = Convert.ToString(result);
            return View();
        }
```

Note: I am trying to avoid sending 'placeHolder' directly to the ActionResult where i need it.

Comment: Put it in TempData and then read it back, assuming you're trying not to add it as a parameter. But then a nornal access of that action won't have access to it and you'll have to guard against that case

Comment: I have used both TempData and Session, however i preferably want the variable to remain alive after the browsing session. Although these methods do work, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 public ActionResult PassCategoryPlaceHolder(string placeHolder)
    {
      var result = placeHolder;
      return RedirectToAction("EditCategory", new { message = result});
    }
```

And in other method:-

```
public ActionResult EditCategory(string message)
 {
   var model = new EditCategoryViewModel();
   model.Message = message;
   return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: For some reason, result is always equal to null for me. However i can see that this method works. I believe this is a fault on my own end.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a Session variable:

```
 public ActionResult PassCategoryPlaceHolder(string placeHolder)
            {

                Session["result"] = placeHolder;
                return RedirectToAction("EditCategory");
            }


    public ActionResult EditCategory()
            {
                var Message = Convert.ToString(Session["result"]);
                return View();
            }
```